# CKEditor image properties missing using Image resize filter with media 2, WYSIWYGs

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg, input-formats

The Ckeditor image properties is missing. I have checked the following:

1. Clear the cache
2. Alter the order filtering according to the image resize filter recommendations. [recommendations for integrating the filter with ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/node/1599070)
3. See if the permission are ok
4. The image resize filter does add the link to the original image, but the image is still showing in the original size, not respecting the width and height set.
5. Upgrade to ckeditor CKEditor 4.0.3
6. It works fine with full html. Same order for the filtering.

what am I missing?

I am using [WYSIWYGs](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), ckeditor, CKEditor 4.0.3 and media 2.

[image: Filter order]

Comment: Here is a shot in the dark. Go to `admin/config/content/ckeditor` click edit on your CKeditor profile and in SHOW EDITOR APPEARANCE there is a plugins section. Perhaps you may need to enable a plugin?

Comment: Thank you for your shot in the dark. :D However, I am not using the ckeditor module. I am using the  WYSIWYGs integration.  It might be a good idea to switch.

Comment: :O sounds like a good idea, let me know how it goes :)